# Error in 'egg_base' option when trying to install feedparser

Tags: python, installation, feedparser

I would like install [feedparser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/).

This is what happens when trying to install feedparser in the Windows command line.

```
> python.exe setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'feedparser does not exist or is not a directory
```

I'm using Python 2.7 (feedparser site states that "It runs on Python 2.4 all the way up to 3.2").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install feedparser using [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip#downloads):

```
pip install feedparser
```

pip is a software tool used to install and manage Python packages. It features a command-line interface which lets you install Python packages by issuing a single command. [How to install pip on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).